# Swift Beginner help : Editor placeholder in source file

Tags: swift, xcode

I am a beginner at Swift. I am trying to implement a sign in and signup page for a new app I am creating. I have looked at other questions asked that are similar to mine but couldn't resolve so I am asking for your help.
I must admit I am following an outdated tutorial which may not be compatible with the current Xcode.

```
@IBAction func signup(_ sender: Any) {

    if username.text == "" || password.text == "" {
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error in form", message: "Please enter a username and password", preferredStyle: <#T##UIAlertControllerStyle#>.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Error messages I am receiving

1) Static member 'Alert' cannot be used on instance of type 'UIAlertControllerStyle'

2) Editor placeholder in source file

Can anyone offer any guidance? I can preview the page and it looks good but the build fails.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unrelated but if you are new to Swift you should be learning Swift 3, not Swift 2.

Comment: @maddy thanks. I was following a tutorial which happens to be built on swift 2 so I will try to find an updated one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors are on this line:

```
var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error in form", message: "Please enter a username and password", preferredStyle: <#T##UIAlertControllerStyle#>.Alert)
```

Note the placeholder text after `preferredStyle:`. Remove that and put the proper value:

```
var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error in form", message: "Please enter a username and password", preferredStyle: .Alert)
```

Unrelated to your issue, do not call `self.dismiss...` in the alert action. The alert will be dismissed automatically when the user taps on any button.

Comment: Thanks very much @rmaddy. This has resolved my issue. I will find a project compatible with Swift 3.